# Are universally valid possibilistic theories possible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

This is a spin-off of the following question: [Are Thomas Breuer's subjective decoherence and Scott Aaronson's freebits with Knightian freedom the same things in essence?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98001/)

Given that Thomas Breuer has proven that universally valid theories either deterministic or probabilistic are impossible, I wonder whether the result extends to possibilistic (rather than probabiblistic) theories as well.

By possibilistic physical theories I mean such theories in which the most complete physical description of a system includes uncertain probability. For instance, those who employ the mathematical apparatus of Dempster-Shafer theory, Graded possibilities, Sugeno Lambda-measures, Belief and Plausibility measures, Fuzzy set theory and
others studies under recently-developed [Generalized Information Theory (GIT)](http://worldtracker.org/media/library/Science/Probability%20&%20Statistics/Uncertainty%20And%20Information%20-%20Foundations%20Of%20Generalized%20Information%20Theor;%20y%20George%20J.%20Klir%20%28Wiley,%202006%29.pdf)

Can such theory be universally valid in absolute (rather than relative) sense (albeit having even less predictive power than a probabilistic theory)?

Comment: Or... you could read the definition of a physical theory in detail before embarking on a quest for a white rabbit.

Comment: if you ask whether a theory with undetermined parameters can be considered universal (in the sense quoted), maybe, but maybe it would **not** explain that much also

Comment: @Nikos M. What if such theory is the best possible physical description of a system, in principle?

Comment: then that is the way it is

Comment: *"What do you mean by 'valid in absolute sense'"*? A theory is valid if it makes correct predictions. It's invalid if it doesn't make any predictions, or if they are false. There isn't much more to it.

Comment: @ACuriousMind look into the linked papers. Particularly, https://homepages.fhv.at/tb/cms/?download=tbPHILSC.pdf and http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/950/1/Exo-theories.pdf

Comment: How is this a physics question?

Comment: This seems metaphysical to me.

Comment: If you want to import philosophical terms into a physics forum, you need to define them. To most physicists, a universally valid theory is one that correctly predicts the externally observable outcomes of any isolated physical system regardless of composition or complexity, either exactly or probabilistically. From your references it seems you have a grander notion in mind. You should state it here explicitly. For the record, I rather doubt that "universally valid theory" has any meaning outside the narrow, naive one given by physicists - but that's a philosophy question.