# Quantum non-equilibrium in various quantum interpretations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

[Quantum non-equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_non-equilibrium) is a hypothetical situation in which a quantum system does not follow the Born rule.

In Copenhagen interpretation, Born rule is postulated as a law, while in MWI and Bohmian mechanics it is not.

In Bohmian mechanics it was shown that once a system reaches quantum equilibrium, it remains there due to Schroedinger's equation.

Quantum non-equilibrium has not been ever detected despite searches.

That said, I wonder whether quantum non-equilibrium is linked to self-reference and, possibly, free will.

Particularly, whether one can explain in terms of quantum non-equilibrium the following phenomena:

- Subjective decoherence, [introduced by Thomas Breuer](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227207921_Subjective_decoherence_in_quantum_measurements)
- Quantum immortality, [introduced by Max Tegmark](https://space.mit.edu/home/tegmark/PDF/everett2.pdf)
- Freebits, [introduced by Scott Aaronson](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98001/are-thomas-breuers-subjective-decoherence-and-scott-aaronsons-freebits-with-kn?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C141.1052).

In these cases it seems, the Born rule is violated. This may hint that from the point of view of an observer, a system properly containing himself violates the quantum equilibrium. Copenhagen interpretation is explicitly not applicable to self-reference experiments, so even if quantum equilibrium is violated, Copenhagen interpretation is irrelevant. Max Tegmark proposed Quantum Immortality as an argument in favor of MWI.

Thus, the questions are:

- Can subjective decoherence and quantum immortality be explained via quantum non-equilibrium?
- Can detection of quantum non-equilibrium decide the choice between quantum interpretations in favor of MWI and Bohm as opposed to Copenhagen?